# Schengen Visa number of entries

Tags: schengen

Thank you, All. Appreciate your answers.

Now I have a clearer itinerary. Arrive at Brussels on Aug 7, leave immediaty to finland, return to Brussels on the 12 and Leave Brussels on the 16.

Will 10 days validity and 2 entries, work?

From your answers, if I am not mistaken, would work. Is that correct ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you flying direct from Belgium to Finland and back, or will you be transferring through another airport or airports?  If so, which airport(s)?

Comment: Planning to fly directly to finland. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can enter the Schengen zone twice. A direct flight between two Schengen countries or through a third Schengen country does not mean leaving Schengen. A flight through London or a similar non-Schengen airport would mean leaving Schengen.

So everything is fine if you go directly from Belgium to Finland.

Comment: That is as long as you mentioned going to Finland in the visa application or go for less time than you spend in Belgium.

Comment: @Willeke or your plans genuinely changed after applying and before going.

Comment: @MartinBonner, a genuine change of plans might still look like deception, and it is a good idea to avoid giving that impression.

Answer (score 2):

I may have missed an earlier (later modified or deleted) message, but I am a bit confused. Why is people talking about two entries? Do you already have a dual-entry Schengen visa or are you asking about what visa to apply for?

Travelling like this:
non-Schengen -> Belgium -> Finland -> Belgium -> non-Schengen
would use up one entry on a Schengen visa.

Landing in Belgium you will go through passport control there. It does not matter whether you chose to leave the airport or continue straight to your connecting flight. In Belgium your passport will get an entry stamp and the clock will start or your time in the Schengen Area.

Arriving in Finland your passport will not be stamped as you arrive from within the Schengen Area (having been checked in Belgium). Returning to Belgium will not get you any new passport stamp either and you will still be on your first entry. It does not matter how many times you travel back and forth.

Eventually leaving the Schengen Area from Belgium you will get you an exit stamp and the clock will stop on your time in the Schengen Area.

If this is your complete itinerary in the Schengen Area you need a single-entry visa. Your stay in the Schengen Area will be 10 calendar days, so a 10-day visa will be enough, assuming your departing flight is not delayed. Unlike some other countries, it is not enough for the visa to be valid on arrival; a Schengen visa must remain valid until you eventually leave the Schengen Area.

Comment: You are right, a single entry would be enough. It is OP who mentioned two entries.

Comment: You can see the earlier version of the question (or, more generally, the version history of any question or answer) by clicking the link that says *edited <some time> ago.*  Welcome to Travel.

Comment: Thank you, Arne. That's really a complete and detail information.
I think I was lack of knowledge on what Schengen countries means and how they work together.
Your answer (and others, as well) helped in clarifying that confusion.
Thanks again.